# No-op function as conditional replacement for stopifnot()

Tags: r, function

Is there a no-op function in R so that, even if the parameters would be expensive to evaluate, it returns immediately? I'm looking for a conditional replacement of the `stopifnot` function.

```
> noop(runif(1e20))
# returns immediately and uses no memory
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this would do:

```
noop <- function(...) invisible(NULL)
```

as lazy evaluation comes to the rescue here:

```
R> system.time(replicate(1e4, noop(runif(1e2))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01 
R> system.time(replicate(1e4, noop(runif(1e5))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
R> system.time(replicate(1e4, noop(runif(1e8))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01 
R> system.time(replicate(1e4, noop(runif(1e11))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01 
R>
```

so even when we increase N no runtime increase can be seen.

Comment: Thank you. Is anything like this pre-defined in base or in any package?

Comment: Not that I know of, so just add the one line to your ~/.Rprofile or Rprofile.site or ...